# get mark position in ms charts on mouse click

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, c#-4.0, mschart

I m making a chart using MS Charts.
Now the chart has mark points from where i want to get the coordinates
if user clicks on the mark points.

I want interactivity in the chart such that on clicking on the mark points i can retrive the cordinates (x-axis and y-axis) for the mark points.

For example for the graph:-

[image: graph]

on clicking on the orange dots or blue dots i want to get the cordinates for that point,

for example the first blue point is (10/11/2011, 49)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<pre>void chart_MouseDown(Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    HitTestResult result = chart.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    switch(result.ChartElementType)
    {
    case case ChartElementType.DataPointLabel:
        DateTime start = DateTime.FromOADate(result.Series.Points[result.PointIndex].XValue);
        ...
        break;
    }
}</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the MS chart samples (http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart), see section *"Chart features > Interactive charting > Selection of Data Point"*:

```
private void chart1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
  // Call Hit Test Method
  HitTestResult result = Chart1.HitTest( e.X, e.Y );

  if( result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint )
  {
    // index of the clicked point in its series
    int index = result.PointIndex;
    // actual values
    Console.WriteLine(result.Series.Points[result.PointIndex].XValue);
    Console.WriteLine(result.Series.Points[result.PointIndex].YValues[0]);                                                              
  }
}
```

Comment: i m only getting index of the point(1,2,3,4) for the x axis. How do i get the actual x axis labels(dates) on clicking on the points.

Comment: I m using DataBindCrossTable to bind the data to the chart.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869585/spline-chart-how-to-get-the-clicked-item/36870298#36870298) for an example that show how to get at the values. You may need to convert from double to datetime..