# Spline chart, how to get the clicked item?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, charts, click

I'm working whit charts on c#.

I would like to know a way of get the iten (the spline) clicked on the chart to do something like change color or hide.

[image]

Comment: I've never worked with them myself (why I'm not answering) but if the chart control doesn't have these events by default I'm sure you could try something which uses a mouse click event and then just get the position from that and check against all your spline paths to see if any cross the clicked point or near by (exact pixel accuracy would make it hard for a user to click each spline)

Comment: Good catch; but especially for Spline&Line charts the HitTest simply don't cut it as it will miss the values for all the parts between datapoints, ie, for most of the lines or curves..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can** check the clicked item using `HitTest`, as suggested..:

```
private void chart1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    HitTestResult result = chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    // now do what you want with the data..:
    if (result.Series != null && result.PointIndex >= 0)
        Text = "X = " + result.Series.Points[result.PointIndex].XValue + 
            "   Y = " + result.Series.Points[result.PointIndex].YValues[0];
}
```

To help the user you can indicate a possible hit:

```
private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    HitTestResult result = chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    Cursor = result.Series != null ? Cursors.Hand : Cursors.Default;
}
```

Do your users a favor by making the spline lines a little larger:

```
eachOfYourSeries.BorderWidth = 4;
```

Of course the chart you show makes a controlled clicking impossible without zooming in first..

Now if all you want is hiding a `Series` or changing its `Color` the `HitTestResult`  is good enough:

```
 result.Series.Enabled = flase;
```

or

```
 result.Series.Color = Color.Fuchsia;
```

But to access the clicked values, it may not be..:

Note that especially a `Spline` or a `Line` graph, need only very **few** `DataPoints` to create their lines; so the result from `HitTest` simply is not enough; it **will** tell you which series was clicked and also the **closest** `DataPoint` but to get at the correct **values** you still may need to **convert the pixels to data values**.

So instead of the `HitTest` result you may prefer to use the handy function `PixelPositionToValue`:

```
 float px = (float)yourChartArea.AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.X);
```

This will get all the values between the actual `DataPoints`. Of course you can do the same for the Y-Values:

```
 float py = (float)yourChartArea.AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(e.Y);
```

**Note** that you can only use these function when the chart is not busy with determining the layout; officially this is only during any of the three `Paint` events. But I found that in practice a mouse event is also fine. You will get a null value when the chart is not ready..